# Why is my python regex pattern not matching the whole string?

Tags: python, regex

I wish to match a url string with my regex pattern: `r'.+'`.
I expect this pattern to fully match the url string, but that's not happening. I'm getting the following output:

***Output:***

```
url string: https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup?ssrc=head&returnurl=%2fusers%2fstory%2fcurrent
matched string: <re.Match object; span=(0, 85), match='https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup?ssrc=head&>
```

Clearly, the match leaves out a chunk of the url string by the end. My pattern doesn't match the `returnurl=%2fusers%2fstory%2fcurrent` part of the url string. Why is this happening? Should I be using something other than `r'.+'` for my pattern?

***Code:***

```
def getQueryParameters(url):
    print(f"url string: {url}")
    pattern = re.compile(r'.+')
    match = pattern.search(url)
    print(f'matched string: {match}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup?ssrc=head&returnurl=%2fusers%2fstory%2fcurrent"
    getQueryParameters(url)
```

Answer (score 3):

Printing the Match Object itself doesn't display the whole match. If you print `match.group(0)` instead of `match`, you will see your regex does match the whole string.

Comment: Notice that there is no closing quote mark on the `match='...` part of the match object's representation. This is the `re` module's way of indicating that the string is incomplete, while still limiting the representation's length so it's not too annoying when you `print` it.